# How to get image inside a form item in google apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-apps-script-api

I have multiple multiple choice questions and checkboxes with images inside them. I am trying to compile all the questions into a doc file. How do I get the images inside the questions? They are not in a separate Image Item.
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1qdqNcaaiKxOoi4IiNc_3xcr1X3uw84qnV7mqMzcQA-0/edit?usp=sharing (This is a sample form containing an Image inside the question in case it isn't clear from the text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, at the moment there is no way to get/set images in multiple choice questions using Apps Script.*

#### Feature Request:

There is already a feature request for setting images using FormApp, which can be found at the following link:

- [Add an image to a Google Form item (different from ImageItem)](https://issuetracker.google.com/135828271)

You should star this issue to let Google know that this is a highly requested feature so that they can prioritise feature requests.

Alternatively, create a second Feature request specifically about *getting* the image and link to this one. The link to flie a feature request for Apps Script is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905).

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been assigned and is expected to come soon. https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/135828271 star this issue for progress updates